# Display JSON object in ionic2

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Im trying to display below JSON object in an ionic2 application. I am getting a blank screen while running the application. i tried some tutorials but no progress.

```
 [
  {
    "program_id": 1000,
    "programName": "Luna_Titan_L",
    "costElement": "Material Cost",
    "trackingID": "LT001S",

  },
  {
    "program_id": 1001,
    "programName": "Luna_Titan_L",
    "costElement": "Material Cost",
    "trackingID": "LR001S"
  },

.....
]
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  progs: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
    this.http.get('http://url.com/api').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.progs = data;
    });

 }

}
```

**home.html**

```
  <ion-list>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let prog of progs">
      {{prog.programName}}
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON though...? Did you just cut it down for demo purposes? Does your console output any error?

Answer (score 0):

Move the service call outside of the constructor and place it inside ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.http.get('http://url.com/api').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.progs = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: yeah if it is working fine..what problem are you getting here?

Comment: im getting a blank page

Comment: debug and see if you are getting the data

Comment: @Abhishek are you using ionic serve or device/emulator?

Comment: @suraj ionic serve

Comment: do some console logs and check..you  will have to debug

Comment: Itried belwo tutorial and its works fine for me. But nothing happens When im trying my own api.

`export class HomePage {
 
  posts: any;
 
  constructor(public http: Http) {
 
    this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/new/.json?limit=10').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.posts = data.data.children;
    });
 
  }`


`<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts">
     {{post.data.url}}
    </ion-item>
 </ion-list>`

Comment: that is what debug and see

Answer (score 0):

While it is better to do asynchronous calls in lifecycle hooks rather than the constructor as @Sajeetharan mentions in his answer, your issue is the view gets loaded before `progs` is set. Use an `*ngIf` to check for the value so that it gets loaded after the value is set.

```
<ion-list *ngIf="progs">

    <ion-item *ngFor="let prog of progs">
      {{prog.programName}}
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
```